# How to run code (Google/Doubleclick Ads) without block main thread

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to run Google Ads code without block main thread? Google Pagespeed Insights shows me a warning **"Reduce the impact of third-party code"**: ***Third-party code blocked the main thread for ...***

```
Third-Party                   Size         Main-Thread Blocking Time
Google/Doubleclick Ads        193 KB       253 ms
```

I've placed a script to the end of the page in the footer.

```
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxx" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

I tried to add "data-aload data-original=..." but it doesn't help. Maybe it would a right choice to use requestAnimationFrame() or setTimeOut(), but I don't know how to implement it on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add script dynamically. NB there is no need to add `async` since browser [considers all dynamic script async by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes)

```js
const loadScript = (src, id, callback) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src; // URL for the third-party library being loaded.
    script.id = id; // e.g., googleMaps or stripe
    script.defer = true; // make sure that browser will run script after page loaded
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    script.onload = () => {
      if (callback) callback(); // conditional callback
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How to pass "data-ad-client" parameter to script element?

Comment: You can use `setAttribute`. `script.setAttribute('data-ad-client', 'value')` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Comment: also make sure that you running `loadScript` after main tasks finished.

Comment: Ads do not load at all with this method.

Comment: For anyone coming across this answer now... Google say not to use `script.onload`, because the code is split between files, and so it's not a reliable way to know all of the scripts have loaded. See https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/common_implementation_mistakes#scenario-1:-relying-on-gpt.js-script-tag-listeners

Comment: Also... deferring the script is good practice, but doesn't stop it from blocking the main thread.

Comment: Thank for update. What is recommended solution now?